# Grid (table) in Google web app adds 4px width to every column, but I need a width of 0px

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script

I created a grid in a Google web app. I was hoping to get the grid to the size (0px, 0px), but I get (12px, 0px) since every column inside of the grid seems to have 4px added to their width for no reason.

Here's what was done to the grid (all at once):

1. The grid's width was set to "0px"
2. The grid's height was set to "0px"
3. The width of the cells inside of the grid were individually set to "0px"
4. The height of the cells inside of the grid were individually set to "0px"
5. The grid's line-height was set to "0px"
6. The line-height of the cells inside of the grid was individually set to "0px"
7. The padding of the grid was set to "0px"
8. The padding of the cells inside of the grid were individually set to "0px"
9. The function ".setCellSpacing(0)" was called on the grid.
10. The function ".setCellPadding(0)" was called on the grid.

*Note: no borders or margins were used on the grid nor the cells inside of it.

Here's some code you can try to see what I'm talking about.

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();

  var grid = app.createGrid(3,3);

  //Used outlines since they don't affect the size of the object
  grid.setStyleAttribute("outline-style","solid");
  grid.setStyleAttribute("outline-width","1px");
  grid.setStyleAttribute("outline-color","red");

  grid.setCellPadding(0);
  grid.setCellSpacing(0);
  grid.setStyleAttribute("width","0px");
  grid.setStyleAttribute("height","0px");
  grid.setStyleAttribute("line-height","0px");
  grid.setStyleAttribute("padding","0px");
  for(var x = 0; x<3; x++){
    for(var y = 0; y<3; y++){
      grid.setStyleAttribute(y,x,"width","0px");
      grid.setStyleAttribute(y,x,"height","0px");
      grid.setStyleAttribute(y,x,"line-height","0px");
      grid.setStyleAttribute(y,x,"padding","0px");
    }
  }

  app.add(grid);

  app.add(app.createLabel("^ The grid is right here. It's width is non-zero for some reason"));

  return app;
}
```

Comment: I noticed that setting each cell to contain an empty SimplePanel did bring the size down to (3px, 0px), but obviously that's not enough.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues here:

1. The cells are automatically populated with `&nbsp;`, so that needs to be cleared (removes 3 * 3px), and
2. [webkit has a bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39381) which leaves an effective 1px width for a cell set to zero width meaning that your only option to drop below 3px is to set the cell to display:none

Try adding these lines to your loop:

```
grid.setStyleAttribute(y,x,"display","none");
grid.setText(y, x, "")
```

Comment: In my case, I need the cell's width to be zero. What I'm doing is intentionally overflowing the cell's contents but I don't want the cells themselves to occupy space (this can be partially solved with negative margins, but it's not really solving the problem).

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think the problem will be fixed in a rush. The bug was reported in 2010.